# Что называют представлениями в Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Достаточно часто сталкиваюсь с этим термином, однако пока что до конца не понял, представление - это что-то вроде контейнера для элементов разметки или эти элементы тоже являются представлениями, также, как "контейнеры", в которых они находятся

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В случае Android представление - это почти всегда некорректный (обычно машинный) перевод слова View, так что это любой элемент верстки. Просто `View` или его наследники.

Лично я других значений этого слова не встречал.

Answer (score 1):

"В каждом файле макета должен быть всего один корневой элемент, в качестве которого должен выступать объект **представления** (View) или **представления** группы (ViewGroup). После определения корневого элемента можно приступать к добавлению дополнительных объектов макета или виджетов в качестве дочерних элементов для постепенного формирования иерархии **представлений**, которая определяет ваш макет."
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout?hl=ru

В программирование (в общем) часто используется этот термин для обозначение элементов архитектуры приложения, для "**показывания**", пользователю информации.